# Is the word "effect" a synonym for "hangover"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

What are the synonyms for "hangover" in the phrase "pandemic hangover"?

I don't know whether the word "effect" can convey its essence or not? Is there any better choice?

Comment: Someone may come up with an interesting idea, but I don't believe there's a synonym for the work hangover in the context it's being used. It might not even be fair to ask for one. There are, without doubt, many words that could *generally* mean, "the effects felt or consequences experienced by someone or something following the pandemic," but the word "hangover" has been specifically chosen due to its context involving headaches, feeling terrible, and the juxtaposition of having to endure something horrific due to an experience deemed desirable (which the pandemic wasn't). ... (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ...  This use reminds me of Terry Pratchett's character of Bilious, "the oh god of hangovers." Consequently, I think it's a stretch to ask for a synonym. This is a great example of literary creativity. Maybe "the pandemic trots" or "pandemic whiplash," neither of which is nearly as good as "pandemic hangover."

Answer (score 2):

A word has both a meaning and a connotation.

A hangover (in the literal sense) is the effect of drinking alcohol. But the connotation of "hangover" is very different.  It has a connotation of a sick, aching, heavy, feeling.  It carries these into the metaphor. So "effect" doesn't have the same sense, and is only a synonym in a narrow sense.

"The pandemic hangover" has connotations of a sickness, in society and culture resulting from the the pandemic.